I want to know when spring-data-redis supports commands like hexpire
To use ttl for hashkey field, I want to use hexpire, the command applied to the latest redis, but I wonder if there is a reflection plan in spring-data-redis.
I used redisson before, but I support command in redis, so I don't want to use it anymore.
Does anyone know when it will be reflected?
redis support 7.4.0
lettuce support 6.4.0
spring data redis supports Letters 6.3.2 in 3.4.0.

Ask them here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues
